# ubuntu 12.04 wpa key length only 63 characters

Tags: wireless

if I choose personal wpa my ubuntu 12.04 wifi gui apparently accepts a maximum of 63 characters only instead of the standard 64, which makes it impossible to connect to 64 character protected nets, while enterprise pwa gui shows no such limitation - what can I do? thanks roberto

Maybe my question was not so clearly formulated as I hoped.
What I mean is when I want to connect to a specific wifi net from OpenSUSE I am given a 64 character field tagged "password" where I can type the 64 hex digit string - 0 to 9 and a to f - that I got from the administrator and I get connected.
When I try to connect from Ubuntu I only get a field 63 character long to type in. The string last digit is truncated and I can't get connected.

Comment: Well it works for me. Be sure to enter only hex digits. For example, it will accept: 000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f I am using Ubuntu 1210 but it was the same with 1204

Answer (score 0):

The network manager will accept 63 ascii characters or 64 hex characters. The 63 ascii characters are taken as a passphrase and converted to a 256 bits hex key. The 64 hex characters are the key.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WPA_key